# Why is my thread count so high

Tags: windows-7

In my Windows (i7) task Manager under Performance, the Thread is bouncing around 1315 and handles 38031. Why these numbers are so high?  I have 2 cores and 4 logical processors.

Comment: why are you concerned? there are lot of system processes running in background. For instance, my thread count is at 1344, and handle count is 92,200. What's the actual problem you're facing?

Comment: My car idles at 1500 rpm. Why are my revs so high????

Answer (score 4):

It's just normal things that a normal system does. On my system right now, both numbers are higher than yours.

Top thread consumers on my system include the OS (178 threads), MSN (72 threads), The task manager (71 threads), and Skype (50 threads). Total threads are over 1,300.

The top handle consumer is the OS itself (over 5,000 handles), explorer (the desktop manager, not IE) is using 1,640 handles. Services are consuming over 1,300 and MSN is over 1,300. The total is over 35,000.

This is all just normal activity on a typical system.

Comment: Thanks, just trying to understand the basic here so please excuse my ignorance. Is a tread like a lane on the vCPU and I can have multiple lane per CPU? Is this what is meant by multi-tread? what is the max number tread on a i7?

Comment: A thread is an execution vehicle that runs a section of code. The thread limit on the CPU doesn't matter since 99.99% of these threads aren't on the CPU. (The OS only schedules a thread on the CPU if that thread has work to do. Most of these threads are waiting for work to do.)

Answer (score 3):

Go to the `Processes` tab and check out which applications are the owners.  The numbers seem high, but they are actually not uncommon.  You don't have much to worry about, but it will be helpful for you to know this in the future.

If you can't see thread and handle count, go to `View -> Select Columns` and check `Handles` and `Threads`.

Comment: And make sure to hit "show processes from all users".

Comment: I was not worrying. I just had the need to know and understand why things are the way they are.